# Python Class inheritance and using variables

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and trying to use class inheritance, and haven't been able to wrap my head around sharing variables.  I have two classes so far, `Scan` and `Ping`:

> **scan.py**

```
class Scan(object):
    """ Super class for scans """
    identifier = str(random.getrandbits(128))
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    results_dir = "/tmp/{}/".format(identifier)
    total_hosts = 0

    def __init__(self, target_hosts=None, target_ports=None):
        self.__target_hosts = target_hosts
        self.__target_ports = target_ports
        self.scan_string = "-sT -O --script auth,vuln"

    @property
    def target_hosts(self):
        return self.__target_hosts

    @target_hosts.setter
    def target_hosts(self, hosts):
        """ Sets target hosts for scan """
        """ Nmap Expects to be single-spaced '1 2 3' separated """
        self.__target_hosts = hosts.replace(", ", " ")
```

> **ping.py**

```
import nmap
from .scan import Scan

class Ping(Scan):
    """ Ping sweep """

    def __init__(self, ping_string, hosts):
        super(Scan, self).__init__()
        self.ping_string = ping_string
        self.hosts = hosts
```

In my script that pretty much calls everything, I'm attempting:

```
from models.scan import Scan
from models.ping import Ping

s = Scan()
hosts = "192.168.0.0/24"
s.target_hosts = hosts
pinger = Ping(ping_string, s.target_hosts)
```

This line doesn't make sense to me ... if Ping inherits from Scan, why does this only work when I call `s.targets_hosts` ?  Shouldn't I be able to call `target_hosts` from my `Ping` class like `Ping.target_hosts` ?

Comment: In your last question do you mean "call `target_hosts` from a `Ping` ***instance*** like `p = Ping(); p.target_hosts`?"  `<instance>.<attribute>` is different than `<class>.<attribute>` -- both are valid, but very different.

Comment: There is a difference between object instance and a class... Please read some more of that. s is an instance of class Scan. You initiated it by s = Scan(). You can use Scan class as a singleton object too, but without relying on __init__ method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might be making this hard to understand is that it's an odd example. In your example, the correct input for the `hosts` parameter that is needed to make an instance of `Ping` needs to come from a property only accessible from an instance of `Ping` (or its parent `Scan`).

Any method (or property) that has `self` as a parameter relies on a specific instance of that class which needs to be created first. If there was a `staticmethod` or `classmethod` they would be callable directly from the class.

You can only get and set `target_hosts` from a specific instance of the class (in this case either `Scan` or `Ping`). If you call `Scan.target_hosts` or `Ping.target_hosts`, it will return something like `<property at 0x51cd188>`.  This is basically returning an unusable function from the class. It's saying, "The class dictionary contains instructions here on how to return some useful stuff from AN INSTANCE of `<class>`."

If you make an instance of Ping or Scan, you now have access to your `target_hosts` property.

```
>>> scan = Scan()
>>> scan.target_hosts = 'host1, host2, host3'
>>> scan.target_hosts
'host1 host2 host3'
>>> ping = Ping('stuff', 'nonsense')
>>> ping.hosts
'nonsense'
>>> ping.target_hosts = 'host4, host5, host6'
>>> ping.target_hosts
'host4 host5 host6'
```

You could run your script with a dummy Ping instance. This should work.

```
from models.scan import Scan
from models.ping import Ping

dummy = Ping('ignore', 'this')
hosts = "192.168.0.0/24"
dummy.target_hosts = hosts
pinger = Ping(ping_string, dummy.target_hosts)
```

Or, if `Scan` had a `staticmethod`, `Ping` could use it as well.

```
class Scan(object):
    """ Super class for scans """
    identifier = str(random.getrandbits(128))
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    results_dir = "/tmp/{}/".format(identifier)
    total_hosts = 0

    def __init__(self, target_hosts=None, target_ports=None):
        self.__target_hosts = target_hosts
        self.__target_ports = target_ports
        self.scan_string = "-sT -O --script auth,vuln"

    @staticmethod
    def prep_hosts(hosts):
        return  hosts.replace(", ", " ")

    ...
```

and then

```
from models.scan import Scan
from models.ping import Ping

hosts = "192.168.0.0/24"
input_hosts = Ping.prep_hosts(hosts)  # or Scan.prep_hosts(hosts)
pinger = Ping(ping_string, input_hosts)
```